# Why MAE is small but the plots doesnot shows clear relationship in regression analysis

Tags: machine-learning, regression

I have plotted real vs predicted values as a regression task. My test set contains around 5000 and the training set contains around 12000 samples. When I calculate the MAE it comes out very small but when I plot y_test vs predicted it does not seem clear relationship (please see the attached plots)[image: with linear regression]

[image: with random forest regression]

How can I interpret such results? When I see the nature of the plot and MAE, random forest (the second one, MAE 0.028) shows a better relationship than the linear regression (first one MAE 0.059). If I present only MAE then one can conclude my regression models perform really well, but the plot does not show such relation. Can anyone please provide some suggestions in such cases?

Comment: The difference between y_test and y_pred will come out less when you will use random forest model instead of simple regression models like linear regression.It is because the random forest model is very complex and predicts the values better than linear regression using bagging methodology.That is why the graph plot is showing such variation.

Comment: Hi Anshul, I agree with that, my confusion is about the relationship between MAE and the scatter plot. MAE is small but the scatter plot does not shows very good relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common way to improve a model is to transform one or more variables, usually using a “log” transform.

Transforming a variable changes the shape of its distribution. Typically the best place to start is a variable that has an asymmetrical distribution, as opposed to a more symmetrical or bell-shaped distribution.

In general, regression models work better with more symmetrical, bell-shaped curves.Try different kinds of transformations until you hit upon the one closest to that shape. It’s often not possible to get close to that, but that’s the goal.

So let’s say you take the square root of Revenue as an attempt to get to a more symmetrical shape, and your distribution looks like this:

[image]

That’s good, but it’s still a bit asymmetrical. Let’s try taking the log of revenue instead, which yields this shape:
[image]

If you take the log10() of a number, you’re saying “10 to what power gives me that number.” For example, here’s a simple table of four datapoints, including both Revenue and Log(Revenue).

[image: click here]

The interesting thing about this transformation is that your regression is no longer linear. When Temperature went from 20 to 30, Revenue went from 10 to 100, a 90-unit gap. Then when Temperature went from 30 to 40, Revenue went from 100 to 1000, a much larger gap.

Note also that you can’t take the log of 0 or of a negative number (there is no X where 10X = 0 or 10X = -5), so if you do a log transform, you’ll lose those datapoints from the regression. There’s 4 common ways of handling the situation:

1. Take a square root, or a cube root. Those won’t change the shape of the curve as dramatically as taking a log, but they allow 0s to remain in the regression.
2. If it’s not too many rows of data that have a zero, and those rows aren’t theoretically important, you can decide to go ahead with the log and lose a few rows from your regression.
3. Instead of taking log(y), take log(y+1), such that zeros become 1s and can then be kept in the regression. This biases your model a bit and is somewhat frowned upon, but in practice its negative side effects are typically pretty minor.